# Call a JS function in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Can I call a JavaScript function in Wordpress like this?

```
<input type="button" value="" class="domain_submit" onclick="callGetDomain();">
```

Where should I put my JavaScript? at `footer.php`? or what would be the proper way to achieve something like this?

I  put my script in `footer.php`, then I called the function like as I mentioned but no use?

Comment: You shouldn't put your script anywhere, you should include it with `wp_enqueue_script` and you should use proper event listeners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use `onclick="callGetDomain();"` and for the function definition, use a separate js file and include that file using `wp_enqueue_script()`, which is the proper way to call js files in Wordpress.
[Check this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)